# Odd caching behaviour by browsers when using ASP.NET CSS Bundles

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundle, stylebundle

Im really to confused as to whats going on here.

It seems the (System.Web.Optimization.)`Bundle` library puts a filesystem watcher on all the files it has bundled up. Whenever there is a change (say for example I tweak the contents of a CSS file), it rebuilds the bundle.

I've seen this work by making requests to the URL of a CSS bundle in Fiddler, with which it works by regenerating the CSS bundle faultlessly, 100% of the time.

However, in both Firefox and Chrome, and only sometimes, it doesn't *appear* to be hitting the webserver, and continues serving me the old, unmodified CSS.

The weird thing is, even after doing a full cache refresh (ctrl+shift+r), and even going into chrome and deleting *all* cached data, it still serves me exactly the same, old CSS file.

This makes me think the fault / issue is actually within the `Bundle` library -maybe fiddler is passing different request headers or something, that make the `Bundle` handler to behave inconsistently?

Appreciate any help with this matter as its been going on for days.

*Edit*: So i've put together the following code which seems to be working

```
...
var styleBundle = new Bundle(virtualPath, new NoCacheTransform());
...


public class NoCacheTransform : IBundleTransform
{
    public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
    {
        context.EnableOptimizations = false;
        context.UseServerCache = false;
        response.ContentType = "text/css";//text/css; charset=utf-8
        response.Cacheability = HttpCacheability.NoCache;
    }
}
```

A couple of those property assignments might not be necessary, but its more of a head up.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to fingerprint the bundle? Refer to http://madskristensen.net/post/cache-busting-in-aspnet for more info.

Comment: I have tried similar (appending a querystring onto the requested css file with a randomised querystring value) and it makes no difference, making me think that it is not the browser 'at fault'.

Comment: What happens when you request the bundle file directly in Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: It serves the unchanged version.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this is a bug. We're seeing similar behaviour; and there are various bugs that seem to describe this open. Sadly the source is not public, and MS were unable to repro this when I contacted them; so it's gone unfixed :(

https://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/120
https://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/96
https://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/114